# How to Input tag in React native

Tags: react-native

I am working on React native app, In my application I am trying to Input tag with some placeholder  in my application. But I don't know how to implement this so someone please tell me how to achieve this in my Application. Exactly what I want is Input tag with any place holder. But the Input tag should not 
Be like a Reactangle in style which is in Bootstrap. Input tag should be like TextField in Material Ui Design.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>Billing Information</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Name</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Mark" />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 20,
    color: '#ff0000',
  },

  heading: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#ff0000',
  },

  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#0000ff',
    backgroundColor: '#32CD32',
  },

  input: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#0000ff',
  },
});

export default App;
```

If you feel I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for something like this one:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tag-input

Comment: Hi @AnkushRishi I am not looking for Toogle

Comment: I am looking for this kind of Input tag https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/  with placeholder standard.

Comment: did you try this module: https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield

Comment: Please post a picture of the input that you requires.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `react-native-elements` and use its Input component which is similar to the Materiel UI design.

Here is the [link](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html).